# Javascript function parameter won't load

Tags: javascript, parameters, snap.svg

I'm animating an svg file, and in order not to bloat my code I have written the follow function:

```
function animateSingleAtt(svgName, element, attToAnimate, attValue, animationTiming) {
    svgName.select( element ).animate({
        attToAnimate : attValue
    }, animationTiming);
}
```

All parameters are loaded just fine, except for attToAnimate. I have no clue as to why this is – it is just passed to the svg element as an attribute named 'attToAnimate'.

I have tried logging it outside of the animate-function, and when I do that, it's passed just fine.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using `attToAnimate` as a key on an object.  To do this properly, change the code to something like this:

```
function animateSingleAtt(svgName, element, attToAnimate, attValue, animationTiming) {
  var anObject = {};
  anObject[attToAnimate] = attValue;
  svgName.select( element ).animate(anObject, animationTiming);
}
```

This should properly build the object you want to pass to `.animate`

Comment: Great! That did the tricks. Thanks a million!

Comment: Just for the record, with ES6 you can use `{ [attToAnimate]: attValue }` instead of assigning the object to a variable and then set the value.

Comment: @schroffl ... good to know. Thanks